# How to select the value from the table based on category_id USING SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

How to select the value from the table based on category_id?

I have a table like this. Please help me.

**Table A**

```
ID Name category_id
-------------------
 1  A       1
 2  A       1
 3  B       1
 4  C       2
 5  C       2
 6  D       2
 7  E       3
 8  E       3
 9  F       3
```

How to get the below mentioned output from table A?

```
ID Name category_id
--------------------
 1  A     1
 2  A     1
 4  C     2
 5  C     2
 7  E     3
 8  E     3
```

Comment: It may make sense to you, but it's entirely unclear what the rational behind your expected output is. Please add an explanation

Comment: I want 1st name based on category_id if any duplicate values occur ,then it will display duplicate value also based on category id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a row number for each row based on group by **`category_id`** and sort by ascending order of **`ID`**. Then select the rows having row number 1 and 2.

**Query**

```
;with cte as (
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [category_id]
        order by [ID]
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [ID], [Name], [category_id]
from cte
where [rn] < 3;
```

Comment: How do you know that it's "select 2 rows from each category"? It could as easily be "select the first row from each category and all subsequent rows in the category with the same `Name`" The question is entirely unclear at the moment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Yeah, might be `"select the first row from each category and all subsequent rows in the category with the same Name"` too.

Comment: So that suggests that we need *clarity* from the OP, and guidance in the comments to assist them, rather than *answers* based on vague assumptions

Comment: how to put the dynamic value in where condition instead of 3

Answer (score 1):

Kindly run this query It really help You Out.

```
SELECT  tbl.id,tbl.name, tbl.category_id FROM TableA as tbl WHERE 
tbl.name IN(SELECT tbl2.name FROM TableA tbl2 GROUP BY tbl2.name HAVING Count(tbl2.name)> 1)
```

Code select all category_id from TableA which has Name entries more then one. If there is single entry of any name group by category_id then such data will be excluded. In above example questioner want to eliminate those records that have single Name entity like wise category_id 1 has name entries A and B among which A has two entries and B has single entry so he want to eliminate B from result set.